How to Correctly Format Page Numbers with Parentheses and lines in KOMA-Script
How can I format the page number as shown in the pictures, because I tried several times and did not succeed, noting that the code I use is:
\documentclass[
    11pt, 
    a4paper, 
    oneside,
    parskip=half*, % Line spacing for paragraphs
    openright,  % openany -> on which page should new chapters start
    listof=totoc, % Include listings in the table of contents
    bibliography=totoc, % adding a bibliography to the table of contents
    index=totoc, % add index directory to the table of contents
    toc=chapterentrywithdots, % Set dots in the table of contents also for chapters
    numbers=noenddot, % removes the last dot after X.X.X.
    pagesize 
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark,singlespacing=true]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Sets the page style to scrheadings.
\pagestyle{scrheadings}





Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Off-topic: 11pt, a4paper and pagesize are default and therefore not needed. openright would also be default with twoside, which is also a default, but openright is senseless with oneside, because with oneside there is no distinction in left and right pages (and more or less all pages are right pages). And \pagestyle{scrheadings} is already the default after loading scrlayer-scrpage and therefore also not needed.

Have you read commands \chead, \cfoot etc. and \pagemark in the KOMA-Script manual? If not, please do so. Do you know the additional page header and footer examples in the KOMA-Script wiki? Do you know, how to make horizontal rules/lines in LaTeX? Should there really be an Arabic and a Roman page number on the same page? Or should there be only one page number either in the page header or the page footer and if so which one? Please try to make questions as clear as possible.

@cabohah
I am new to Latex and I assume that I have a document that is divided into two parts, the introductory section which includes the abstract, the introduction and the table of contents, where their numbering is Roman. What I need is for the numbering to be in parentheses with horizontal lines on the right and left inside the footer.

@cabohah
The second section is the main section, which consists of chapters, where their numbering is in English numbers and between parentheses, with lines on the right and left in a horizontal manner. The pictures illustrate the idea. Can you give me a very simple example that shows how I make page numbers between parentheses with horizontal lines on the sides inside the footer?

Beginners also can show a minimal working example instead of a code snippet only. And they should follow links and read the linked pages …

Your question is somehow unspecific, e.g., because of the missing minimal working example. And you say you are a very beginner. So this answer will be lengthy, because I try to explain more, than would be needed for better specified question and for a user, who at least knows the basics. But I recommend to not just copy some code, but read the explanation and also the recommended documentation.
There are several possibilities to have a horizontal line in the page footer, which is cut by the page number. There are also several possibilities to add parenthesis to the page number.
The most simple solution, which does not really use the features of scrlayer-scrpage would be something like:
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mwe}

\cfoot*{\rule[.7ex]{.47\linewidth}{1pt}\hfill(\thepage)\hfill\rule[.7ex]{.47\linewidth}{1pt}}% Please don't use this!

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}

Here the only scrlayer-scrpage command is \cfoot*{…}. It configures a centered element in the page footer of page style scrheadings and the corresponding plain style plain.scrheadings, which is used e.g. at pages which start a new chapter. See the scrlayer-scrpage chapter in Part I of the KOMA-Script documentation (available in English and in German) for more information. All other commands are LaTeX basics. If you don't know any of these basics, you should read a LaTeX introduction!
But note, that this is code is really a very basic solution, which should not be used. One problem of the solution is, that the parenthesis and the page number is printed slanted:

This could be changed adding \normalfont to the beginning of the \cfoot* argument. But KOMA-Script provides another feature: Font settings for several standard elements. One of these elements is, e.g., page header and footer, page header, page footer, page number. So to change the font, you could add, e.g., `
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}

somewhere in the document preamble, to remove the slanted default for the page header and footer:

But this also changes the font of the page header. If this is not desired, you can replace pageheadfoot by pagefoot. For more information about \setkomafont also see the KOMA-Script documentation.
But IMHO a better solution would be, to replace \thepage by \pagemark. \pagemark already uses element pagination, which is not slanted by default. And because the parentheses are part of the pagination, they should become part of the \pagemark definition:
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mwe}

\cfoot*{\rule[.7ex]{.47\linewidth}{1pt}\hfill\pagemark\hfill\rule[.7ex]{.47\linewidth}{1pt}}% page footer center element definition with lines and page mark
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagination}{(\thepage)}}% pagenumber in parenthesis

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}

The result is the same as shown above:

But the code is cleaner.
Using a fix length — here 0.47\linewidth — can be correct, if the length of the lines should be constant, for short line numbers like the shown “(1)” and for long line numbers like, e.g., “(999)”. But maybe if the length of the line should depend on the width of the page number, other solutions are needed. We could, e.g., measure the width of the page number:
\cfoot*{%
  \settowidth{\pagenumberwidth}{~\pagemark~}% width of page mark + one space left and right
  \setlength{\pagefooterrulewidth}{\linewidth}%
  \addtolength{\pagefooterrulewidth}{-\pagenumberwidth}%
  \setlength{\pagefooterrulewidth}{0.5\pagefooterrulewidth}%
  \rule[.7ex]{\pagefooterrulewidth}{1pt}\hfill\pagemark\hfill\rule[.7ex]{\pagefooterrulewidth}{1pt}
}


See a LaTeX introduction for \settowidth, \setlength and \addtolength.
With a (more or less) up-to-date LaTeX installation the calculation can be shorten:
\cfoot*{%
  \settowidth{\pagenumberwidth}{~\pagemark~}% width of page mark + one space left and right
  \setlength{\pagefooterrulewidth}{\dimeval{(\linewidth-\pagenumberwidth)/2}}%
  \rule[.7ex]{\pagefooterrulewidth}{1pt}\hfill\pagemark\hfill\rule[.7ex]{\pagefooterrulewidth}{1pt}
}

See LaTeX for authors current version for more information about \dimeval.
But IMHO a smarter solution would be to use a rule of the whole footer width an place a white box with the page mark in the middle:
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mwe}

\ifoot*{\rule[.7ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}}% line in the footer
\cfoot*{\colorbox{white}{\pagemark}}% pagemark in the footer inside a white box (to break the line in the footer)
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagination}{(\thepage)}}% pagenumber in parenthesis

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


Note, I've used \ifoot*{…} here, because with a oneside document it is printed before the \cfoot*{…} element (see the KOMA-Script documentation for more information). But with a twoside document this is only true for right pages. So there you would need to use \lefoot*{} and \lofoot*{} to distinguish even and odd pages or use a trick like:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mwe}

\ifoot*{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.7ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}}% line in the footer
  \makebox[\layerwidth][c]{\colorbox{white}{\pagemark}}% pagemark in the footer inside a white box (to break the line in the footer)
}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagination}{(\thepage)}}% pagenumber in parenthesis

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}

But there is one more solution for the line: You can add a new layer to the page styles headings and scrheadings:
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mwe}

\DeclareLayer[% define a new layer
  background,% use a background layer
  foot,% at the page footer
  contents={\rule{\layerwidth}{1pt}}% rule of the whole layer width
]{numberrule}% name of the layer

\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{numberrule}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{numberrule}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{%
  \colorbox{white}{\usekomafont{pagination}{(\thepage)}}% pagenumber in parenthesis in a white box
}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


As you can see, with this example, you even don't need a \cfoot*{…}, because the line is added using \AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle and the white box is moved into the \pagemark definition (which could also be used with the other examples) and because the default definition for oneside document already uses a page mark in the middle of the footer.
Note, commands \DeclareLayer and \AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle are also documented in the KOMA-Script manual, but in another chapter. They are commands of KOMA-Script package scrlayer, which is used by scrlayer-scrpage. So they are documented in the scrlayer chapter in Part II.
For a twoside document, you would indeed need to move the page mark from the outer position to the middle. But this is also easy:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mwe}

\DeclareLayer[% define a new layer
  background,% use a background layer
  foot,% at the page footer
  contents={\rule{\layerwidth}{1pt}}% rule of the whole layer width
]{numberrule}% name of the layer

\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{numberrule}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{numberrule}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{%
  \colorbox{white}{\usekomafont{pagination}{(\thepage)}}% pagenumber in parenthesis in a white box
}
\ofoot*{}% clean the outer footer position
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% add the page mark at the middle footer position

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}

But perhaps such a straight, horizontal line is a little boring ...
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mwe}

\DeclareLayer[% define a new layer
  background,% use a background layer
  evenpage,%
  foot,% at the page footer
  contents={\tikz{\draw[ultra thick,red!50!black!50](0,0) sin (\layerwidth,1);}}
]{numberruleodd}% name of the layer
\DeclareLayer[% define a new layer
  background,% use a background layer
  oddpage,%
  foot,% at the page footer
  contents={\tikz{\draw[ultra thick,blue!50](0,1) cos (\layerwidth,0);}}
]{numberruleeven}% name of the layer

\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{numberruleeven,numberruleodd}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{numberruleeven,numberruleodd}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{%
  \colorbox{white}{\usekomafont{pagination}{(\thepage)}}% pagenumber in parenthesis in a white box
}
\ofoot*{}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}




I would like to express my deepest gratitude to @cabohah for his immense support and valuable guidance, which had a profound impact on the successful completion of this work. All the solutions worked as I wanted, but I will choose the fifth one because it is the most intelligent.

@MuhammadSalem If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider upvoting (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Hello, I clicked on the check mark and the arrows from the first moment to answer, but I do not know if it was accepted or not because I saw this message.
"
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.
"

You want to set \cfoot and to define a command that does like \hrulefill, but with a rule raised at the vertical center of digits (and parentheses).
\documentclass[
    11pt, 
    a4paper, 
    oneside,
    parskip=half*, % Line spacing for paragraphs
    openright,  % openany -> on which page should new chapters start
    listof=totoc, % Include listings in the table of contents
    bibliography=totoc, % adding a bibliography to the table of contents
    index=totoc, % add index directory to the table of contents
    toc=chapterentrywithdots, % Set dots in the table of contents also for chapters
    numbers=noenddot, % removes the last dot after X.X.X.
    pagesize 
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark,singlespacing=true]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text for the example

% Sets the page style to scrheadings.
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% based on \hrulefill
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chrulefill}{%
  \leavevmode
  \leaders % fill the space
  \hrule height \dimeval{0.5\fontcharht\font`0+0.2pt}
         depth -\dimeval{0.5\fontcharht\font`0-0.2pt}
  \hfill
  \kern\z@
}
\makeatother

\cfoot{\normalfont\chrulefill\ (\thepage)\ \chrulefill}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}


What's the \chrulefill command based on? With
\leaders\hrule <specs> \hfill

TeX is instructed to fill the available space with a rule. The <specs> define the height and depth of the rule: we want a height of half a digit's increased by 0.2pt; in order to get a 0.4pt thick rule, we cancel part of the height by a negative depth.
